# How can I typedef a namespace qualified type?

Tags: c++, typedef

I want to do something along the lines of `#define std::unordered_map my_namespace::my_map`. There are various complicated reasons for why I want to do this (legacy code, future upstream merging, performance, etc.). Unfortunately, `#define` doesn't work with `::` and `typedef` seems to have issues as well. How might I do this?

Typedef's issue:

- `typedef std::unordered_map my_namespace::my_map;` gives the error "Typedef declarator cannot be qualified".
- `namespace std { typedef unordered_map my_namespace::my_map };` gives the error "Cannot define or redeclare 'my_map' here because namespace 'std' does not enclose namespace 'my_namespace'"

Comment: what "issues" does typedef have? I assume the issue is how you use it, but you didnt show how. Please include a [mcve]

Comment: OP, are you trying to replace any usage of `std::unordered_map` with `my_namespace::my_map` or do you just want `my_namespace::my_map` to be `std::unordered_map`

Comment: @NathanOliver I want `std::unordered_map` to be an alias for `my_namespace::my_map`

Comment: @meisel Okay.  Not sure if there is a fix for that.

Comment: What you are asking for isn't possible, unless you make your own C++ compiler.  (I'd start with llvm and clang, and then modify the implementation of std::unordered_map so that it does whatever my_namespace::my_map does.)  Anything short of that will be ODR.

Comment: in that case i'd go for a search&replace over the code, not nice, but still nicer than messing around with the `std` namespace. Or do you want to also be able to call some third party functions and they should use your map instead of the std one?

Comment: Yeah I'll probably just use sed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I typedef a namespace qualified type?

You define a typedef for a (type that is in a namespace) like this:

```
typedef some_ns::type alias;
```

You define a (typedef that is in a namespace) for a type like this:

```
namespace other_ns {
    typedef some_ns::type alias;
}
```

Or, you can use the corresponding `using` syntax, which I recommend:

```
namespace other_ns {
    using alias = some_ns::type;
}
```

---

> I want std::unordered_map to be an alias for my_namespace::my_map

You may not add typedefs into the `std` namespace. That is reserved to the language implementation. This is simply not possible in C++.

---

> ```
> namespace std { typedef unordered_map my_namespace::my_map };
> ```

You have the alias and the target type in wrong order. This makes `std::my_namespace::my_map` an alias of `std::unordered_map`. Or it would, if you were allowed to put the qualified names in the typedef, which you aren't. Considering you intuitively use the order of [alias, type], the `using` syntax should fit you just right.

Regardless, see the previous section about `std` being a reserved namespace.

Comment: Note that it is allowed to add *some* things, like template specialisations, to the `std` namespace.